# Redirect to wrong URL for 301 permanent redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having problems with 301 redirects for a website, some work and some don't. Here is and example for one that doesn't work, I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
Redirect 301 "/services1/services2/services3" "/services2"
```

The redirected page looks like this and it gives a 404 page:
https://www.example.com/services2/services3

Answer (score 0):

Since `Redirect` directive appends rest of the old url to its destination, use `RedirectMatch` to redirect to a specific location

```
RedirectMatch  301 "/services1/services2/services3" "/services2"
```

Comment: @Dorin Are you still getting the same result when you type the old url into browser?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's what helped me maybe it will help somebody else: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^services1/services2/services3/?$ $1/services2$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: @Dorin I am not sure how that helped you. Actually `$n` variable is undefined in your RewriteRule .